# HTTP Error 408 in Python using Pandas and Quandl

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, ipython, anaconda

Working on a Pandas tutorial and I input the following code in IPython notebook (Py3.5):

```
import Quandl
import pandas as pd

api_key = open('quandlapikey.txt','r').read()

fiddy_states = pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_states_and_territories_of_the_United_States')

main_df = pd.DataFrame()

for abbv in fiddy_states[0][1][1:]:
    query = "FMAC/HPI_"+str(abbv)
    df1 = Quandl.get(query, authtoken=api_key)

    if main_df.empty:
        main_df = df1
    else:
        main_df = main_df.join(df)

print(main_df.head())
```

And I get the following traceback/error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
HTTPError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/albatross/anaconda2/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/Quandl/Quandl.py in get(dataset, **kwargs)
    118     try:
--> 119         urldata = _download(url)
    120         if verbose and verbose != 'no':

/home/albatross/anaconda2/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/Quandl/Quandl.py in _download(url)
    313 def _download(url):
--> 314     dframe = pd.read_csv(url, index_col=0, parse_dates=True)
    315     return dframe

/home/albatross/anaconda2/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in parser_f(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, tupleize_cols, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, skip_footer, doublequote, delim_whitespace, as_recarray, compact_ints, use_unsigned, low_memory, buffer_lines, memory_map, float_precision)
    528 
--> 529         return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    530 

/home/albatross/anaconda2/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    280         filepath_or_buffer, encoding,
--> 281         compression=kwds.get('compression', None))
    282     kwds['compression'] = (inferred_compression if compression == 'infer'

/home/albatross/anaconda2/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py in get_filepath_or_buffer(filepath_or_buffer, encoding, compression)
    276     if _is_url(filepath_or_buffer):
--> 277         req = _urlopen(str(filepath_or_buffer))
    278         if compression == 'infer':

/home/albatross/anaconda2/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py in urlopen(url, data, timeout, cafile, capath, cadefault, context)
    161         opener = _opener
--> 162     return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
    163 

/home/albatross/anaconda2/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py in open(self, fullurl, data, timeout)
    470             meth = getattr(processor, meth_name)
--> 471             response = meth(req, response)
    472 

/home/albatross/anaconda2/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py in http_response(self, request, response)
    580             response = self.parent.error(
--> 581                 'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
    582 

/home/albatross/anaconda2/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py in error(self, proto, *args)
    508             args = (dict, 'default', 'http_error_default') + orig_args
--> 509             return self._call_chain(*args)
    510 

/home/albatross/anaconda2/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py in _call_chain(self, chain, kind, meth_name, *args)
    442             func = getattr(handler, meth_name)
--> 443             result = func(*args)
    444             if result is not None:

/home/albatross/anaconda2/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py in http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs)
    588     def http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs):
--> 589         raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
    590 

HTTPError: HTTP Error 408: REQUEST_TIMEOUT

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ErrorDownloading                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-664de7515f81> in <module>()
     10 for abbv in fiddy_states[0][1][1:]:
     11     query = "FMAC/HPI_"+str(abbv)
---> 12     df1 = Quandl.get(query, authtoken=api_key)
     13 
     14     if main_df.empty:

/home/albatross/anaconda2/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/Quandl/Quandl.py in get(dataset, **kwargs)
    138                 print("url:", url)
    139             error = "Error Downloading! {}".format(e)
--> 140             raise ErrorDownloading(error)
    141 
    142     if returns == 'numpy':

ErrorDownloading: Error Downloading! HTTP Error 408: REQUEST_TIMEOUT
```

I don't understand what might be causing this HTTP Error nor do I know how to fix it. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You sure your network is not the issue?

Comment: I've pulled other info from Quandl in previous tutorials without issue. Could it be that I making too many request to their server too quick?